# Dictionary/json assignment - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm working on an assignment where I need to get information from a dictionary based on a user's entry. For instance, I have this dictionary that I have to work with:

```
{
  "north_america":{
      "canada":{
          "ottawa":{
                "population":500,
                "average_age":18
           }
      }
   },
   "south_america":{
      "brazil":{
          "sao_paolo":{
                "population":200,
                "average_age":21
          }
      }
   }
}
```

The point of my program is to return the country depending on which city the user chooses. For example, after the program asks "Which city do you choose", if the user writes "ottawa", my program is supposed to return the name of the country in which ottawa is assigned, so for this case, canada.

Can someone help me out please? Thank you!

Comment: What you tried? what error are you getting?

Comment: Please attempt this first and then come to Stack Overflow with more specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class country_finder():
        def __init__(self):
            original_dict = {
                "north_america":{
                    "canada":{
                        "ottawa":{
                            "population":500,
                            "average_age":18
                        }
                    }
                },
                "south_america":{
                    "brazil":{
                        "sao_paolo":{
                            "population":200,
                            "average_age":21
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            self.new_dict = {}

            for continent in original_dict:
                continent_dict = original_dict[continent]
                for country in continent_dict:
                    country_dict = continent_dict[country]
                    for city in country_dict:
                        self.new_dict[city] = country


        def find_country(self, city_name):
            return self.new_dict[city_name]
    finder = country_finder()
    print(finder.find_country("ottawa"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def displayCountry(citySelected):
    for continent, countryDict in continentlist.items():
        for country,cityDict in countryDict.items():
            for city,value in cityDict.items():
               if(city==citySelected):
                   print(country)

displayCountry("sao_paolo")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your continent dataset should be array, not dict.
It could be like following:

```
data = {
    "north_america": [{
        "canada": {
            "ottawa": {
                "population": 500,
                "average_age": 18
            }
        }
    }],
    "south_america": [{
        "brazil": {
            "sao_paolo": {
                "population": 200,
                "average_age": 21
            }
        }
    }],
}
```

Then iterate each continent, each country. After that get country name and compare capital name with desired one.

```
def solve(capital_wanted: str):
    for continent_name in data.keys():
        for country in data[continent_name]:
            for key in country.keys():
                country_name = key

                break

            capital = get_capital(country[country_name])
            if capital == capital_wanted:
                return country_name

    return None

def get_capital(country_info: dict) -> str:
    for key in country_info.keys():
        capital = key

        break

    return capital

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert solve('ottawa') == 'canada'
    assert solve('sao_paolo') == 'brazil'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
x={
  "north_america":{
      "canada":{
          "ottawa":{
                "population":500,
                "average_age":18
           }
      }
   },
   "south_america":{
      "brazil":{
          "sao_paolo":{
                "population":200,
                "average_age":21
          }
      }
   }
}

city="sao_paolo"
print(next(c for a,b in x.items() for c,d in b.items() for e,f in d.items() if e==city))
```